# Consulta con el return de una función del tipo public FileResult

Tags: asp.net

buenos días, esperando que se encuentren bien tengo una duda o consulta técnica.

Estoy haciendo una página web con .ASP.NET en la cual tengo un botón que al darle click envía por un metodo GET un id a una función que tengo, la función tiene esta forma:

```
public FileResult Download(int id)
{
   try
   {
       //acá va mi código que funciona bien

   }
   catch(Exception ex)
   {
     log.Log(MvcApplication.filtro, "Error en la descarga de documento para el id: " + id)
     return File(content, "application/force-download", itemfile.nombre);
   }
}
```

Mi duda es, yo puedo hacer que esta función me redirija a una página x cuando yo le pase un id que no sea numérico?

Por ejemplo si le mando con postman el valor "104f", me redirija a una página de error que yo cree?

yo sé que por ser una función de tipo FileResult lo que se retorne tiene que ser de tipo **File**, pero existe alguna excepción o forma de cambiar esto?

Muchas Gracias.

Comment: Lo que quieres es verificar el valor que se envía en la petición antes de que se ejecute el método Download?

Comment: Hola @JeffersonCuji , no necesariamente, si yo por ejemplo le mando un valor "123A, va a hacer el try y si se cae va a ir por el catch, y necesito que ahí el return no sea **return File** sino **return redirect** y no sé si se puede hacer eso. Saludos

Comment: El padre de FileResult y de RedirectToAction es ActionResult puedes cambiarlo

Comment: Muchas Gracias, @JeffersonCuji